# How to scan input data in c?

Tags: c

I have a case, I want to make a loop that will stop when the user enters the number 0, in that loop i want to do two things:

1. If the user wants to add data, then the user must enter the number "1" and followed by the data (float), example: 1 2
2. if the user wants to delete the data, the user must enter the number "2", without the accompaniment of any data thereafter. example: 2

example of user inputs:

```
1 5

1 3

2

0
```

C code that I have written is like this:

```
while(option != 0){
    scanf("%d %f",&option,&b);
    if(option == 1){
        Add(&Q,b);
    }else if(option == 2){
        Del(&Q,&b);
    }
}
```

But I have a problem, when I want to delete the data, I have to enter the number "2", only "2", but because of this part of the code:

```
scanf("%d %f",&option,&b);
```

i can't do that, I still have to enter two datas (such as when I want to add the data), but in the delete option i need only input the number "2".

How to do that simply?, help me guys, thanks.

Comment: When deleting, what will you delete?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just fetch the user input for the variable `b` only after checking the value of `option`. That is only iff `option` entered is `1`, scanf for `b`

```
while(option != 0) {
    scanf("%d", &option);
    if (option == 1) {
        scanf("%f", &b);
        Add(&Q,b);
    } else if(option == 2) {
        Del(&Q,&b);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply input data `b` and `option` in different `scanf`'s . Check `option` first and if it is `1` then only take input in `b`. something like this -

```
while(option != 0){
   scanf("%d",&option);   // but always check return of scanf
   if(option == 1){
        scanf("%f",&b);
        Add(&Q,b);
   }
   else if(option == 2){
      Del(&Q,&b);
   }
}
```